# Fill jqGrid dropdown select from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

How i can create dropdown inside jqGrid and populate it from MVC controller ? and then send selected item value from jqGrid in view to controller ?

Answer (score 0):

For your jqgrid colModel:

```
{name: 'example', index: 'example', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: {dataUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")'}}
```

And in your controller:

```
public string ActionName()
{
//return your dropdown list html code
return "<select><option value=\"volvo\">Volvo</option><option value=\"saab\">Saab</option></select>";
}
```

There are a few ways to do it besides using dataUrl. Please refer to [jqgrid doc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editable)